# Testing Observables -- check for side effects on subscribe

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs

I want to test the way an observable will behave from a consumer's perspective.

I can't tell if there are going to be side effects when I subscribe (cold) or not (hot).

Is there a way I can validate this behavior in a unit test?

I have `TestScheduler` from rxjs/testing wired up, but I'm not seeing a good way to validate the number of times the observable has been created.

```
// ...the create method has been mocked to emit after 3 frames
const create$ = api.create(potato).pipe(
  tap(console.log.bind(null, 'object created'))
);
create$.subscribe();
create$.subscribe();
create$.subscribe();

// Test how many times create$ has gotten a subscription, generated a cold observable, and completed.

const timing = '---(a|)'; // wait 3 frames, emit value of `a`, complete
const values = { a: potato };
expectObservable(create$).toBe(timing, values);
```

This test passes, but the "object created" message fires four times (3 for my subscribes, and one from middleware).

I want to write a failing test (true negative) before I change the observable's behavior to match what I'd like for `api.create`.

How can I validate that the create behavior is only executed once?

I've tried:

- `spyOn`, but the actual create method is only called once.
- `Array.isArray(create$.observers)` -- too indirect, only checks if it's hot, not if it behaves as expected.
- `tap(() => runCount++)` \ `expect(runCount).toBe(1)` -- works if I flush the scheduler, but seems outside of the norm for rxjs testing.
- Using `Observable.create` with a factory function to manually track run counts. Also works, somewhat verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the best way I've found so far to verify in a unit test that an inner observable is called only once for every subscription.

1. Create a fake cold observable that acts like your actual operation
2. Use `spyOn` to return that value from your "do the real work" function
3. Call the external api
4. Verify the runCount on the fake cold observable

```
scheduler.run(rx => {
  let runCount = 0;
  const timing = '---(a|)';
  const values = { a: {x:42} };

  // This represents the inner cold observable.
  // We want to validate that it does/does not get called once per subscription
  const mockedCreate$ = rx.cold(timing, values).pipe(
    tap(() => runCount++),
  );
  spyOn(api, 'doCreate').and.returnValue(mockedCreate$);

  const create$ = api.create({x:42}); // internally, calls doCreate
  create$.subscribe();
  create$.subscribe();
  create$.subscribe();
        // Explanation:
        // If api.create wasn't multicasting/sharing the result of the doCreate
        // operation, we'd see multiple actual save operations, not just 1

  rx.expectObservable(create$).toBe(timing, values);
  scheduler.flush();
  expect(runCount).toBe(1, 'how often the "real" create operation ran');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow what you're asking, but I can address your concern about how many times your observable is created:

Once.

```
const create$ = api.create(potato)
```

This creates your observable. Your `.pipe` attachment to the observable is part of the data path from the point of your observable to the subscribers.

```
potato ---(pipe)--->.subscribe()
     +----(pipe)--->.subscribe()
     +----(pipe)--->.subscribe()
     +----(pipe)--->(expectObservable inspection)
```

Instead, it seems that you may want to put in an extra pipe there to share the result. Perhaps unsurprisingly, this pipe is called `share`.

**Input**

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { share, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

let obj: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
let obs: Observable<string> = obj.pipe(tap(() => console.log('tap pipe')));

obs.subscribe((text) => console.log(`regular: ${text}`));
obs.subscribe((text) => console.log(`regular: ${text}`));
obs.subscribe((text) => console.log(`regular: ${text}`));

let shared: Observable<string> = obs.pipe(share());

shared.subscribe((text) => console.log(`shared: ${text}`));
shared.subscribe((text) => console.log(`shared: ${text}`));
shared.subscribe((text) => console.log(`shared: ${text}`));

obj.next('Hello, world!');
```

**Output**

```
tap pipe
regular: Hello, world!
tap pipe
regular: Hello, world!
tap pipe
regular: Hello, world!
tap pipe
shared: Hello, world!
shared: Hello, world!
shared: Hello, world!
```

Comment: Great! Yes, I'd like to do a share(), as you say. Or a publishReplay(), refCount().

But first, I want to "write the failing test" that verifies cold observable behavior for my use case.

Comment: If you have in mind a side effect that might happen, you should test for it immediately after the `subscribe` and before you provide a value through the observable data path.